# Hide deleted Teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

I've created a team just to test the new feature and deleted it afterwards. However, if I search for it, I'm still able to find the team even logged out.

Should I blame caching? Or the query is not filtering out deleted teams?

[image: deleted team]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed! Added a filter to the elastic search.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a bug. It will be fixed soon!